# How do I find the moment generating function?

Tags: calculus, integration, moment-generating-functions

How do I find the mgf for the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{4}(1+x)$ when $0<x<2$? I do know I have to use integration but I'm not sure about how to do the calculation, or if I need to use integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

To help you get started

$$\mathbb{E}[\exp(tX)] = \int_{0}^2 \exp(tx) f(x) dx= \int_0^2 \exp(tx) \frac14 (1+x)dx$$

Integration by parts might help.

Edit:
\begin{align}
&\int_0^2 \exp(tx) \frac14 (1+x)dx \\
&= \frac14 \int_0^2 \exp(tx) (1+x)dx \\
&=\frac14 \left( \frac{\exp(tx)}{t}(1+x)|_{x=0}^{x=2}  - \frac1t\int_0^2 \exp(tx) dx\right) \\
&= \frac14 \left( \frac{3\exp(2t)-1}{t} -\frac{1}{t^2} \exp(tx)|_{x=0}^{x=2}\right)\\
&= \frac14 \left( \frac{3\exp(2t)-1}{t} -\frac{\exp(2t)-1}{t^2} \right)\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. I know integration by parts is necessary but I can't seem to find and answer when I use integration by parts.

Comment: hmmm... why can't you find the answer? the answer should be in terms of $t$.

Comment: You want to integrate $\exp(tx)$ and differentiate the remaining part in integration by parts.

Comment: After integration, I'm getting $\frac{1}{4}(xe^(tx)(x+2)/x)$ evaluated at 0 to 2, which doesn't seem correct to me.

Comment: Note that $\int \exp(tx) dx = \frac{\exp(tx)} {t} +C$

Comment: So would I have to do integration by parts more than once?

Comment: Once should be sufficient.

Comment: So my final answer is (e^(2t))/t. I hope this is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58622/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-pmk1007).